# Changing isChecked without triggering Checked/Unchecked in ToggleButton

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a ToggleButton. Whenever someone checks it, It will set a value to registry (regedit.exe) and If someone uncheck, It will remove the value.

Now, when I run the application again, I want to check whether the value is on the Registry or not so I make the ToggleButton Checked (If the value is there) or unchecked (If it's not there).

```
if (registry.GetValue("AppName") == null)
{
    Toggle.IsChecked = false;

}
else
{
   Toggle.IsChecked = true;
}
```

The problem here is that after checking and finding the value in registry, It wil put 'IsChecked' to true, and that will trigger 'Checked' and make it write in registry again.

Comment: you can have private fields backed up with properties and set the field value in constructor or Initialize method in your View Model

Comment: This is a very common issue people face when using databinding. There are many *dirty* and *hacky* ways to fix this issue. The most appropriate and cleanest approach would be: *Do not manipulate ui controls from code. Manipulate the thing which ui controls bind to, so in your case, manipulate the viewmodel. Also disable binding during ViewModel manipulation. Once finished, enable binding and ui will refresh.* So the flag in your viewmodel will be `true` and when the ui binds to it, it will become checked. This will trigger event that it is checked but your viewmodel is already in sync.

Comment: Therefore, nothing will happen. This is also useful so during loading and manipulating the viewmodel, you do not have events being thrown all over the place and slowing down the load. In other words, your code should not be clicking ui controls (`control.Checked = true;`). That is the job of the user. Your job is to be manipulating the viewmodel.

Answer (score 0):

With = operator you are assigning to the boolean, thats why it triggers an event, if you want to check whether the value is, try to compare instead (with == operator)

```
// dont do this
Toggle.IsChecked = registry.GetValue("AppName") == null ? false : true;

// do this instead
if (Toggle.IsChecked == true) // registry is apparently not null
{
    // double check
    if (registry.GetValue("AppName") != null)
    {
        // registry is not null
        bRegistryIsEmpty = false;
    }
}
else // registry is apparently null
{
    // double check
    if (registry.GetValue("AppName") == null)
    {
        // registry is null
        bRegistryIsEmpty = true;
    }
}

// or just do this
bRegistryIsEmpty = registry.GetValue("AppName") == null ? true : false;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a boolean flag in your event handler that prevents the event handler from invoking itself:

```
private bool _handle = true;
private void CheckBox_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (!_handle)
        return;

    bool isChecked = registry.GetValue("AppName") != null;
    _handle = false; //prevent the event handler from being invoked
    Toggle.IsChecked = isChecked;
    _handle = true; //enable the event handler again
}
```